# Why is my $watch not working in my directive test - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive in which I pass in an `attrs` and then it is watched in the directive.  Once the `attrs` is changed, then an animation takes place.  My `attrs` always is undefined when the `$watch` gets triggered.

```
App.directive('resize', function($animate) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.resize, function(newVal) {
      if(newVal) {
        $animate.addClass(element, 'span8');
      }
    });
  };
});
```

And here is my test:

```
describe('resize', function() {
  var element, scope;
  beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    var directive = angular.element('<div class="span12" resize="isHidden"></div>');
    element = $compile(directive)($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
    scope = $rootScope;
  }));

  it('should change to a span8 after resize', function() {
    expect($(element).hasClass('span12')).toBeTruthy();
    expect($(element).hasClass('span8')).toBeFalsy();
    element.attr('resize', 'true');
    element.scope().$apply();
    expect($(element).hasClass('span8')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

When the `attrs` changes, my watchers `newValue` is undefined and so nothing happens. What do I need to do to make this work?  Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/DzFqjwUzohChZ6ANYNKk)

Comment: Could you make a fiddle for this?

Comment: Instead of `element.attr('resize', 'true');`, try changing that line to `element.scope().resize = true;`.  Does that work?

Comment: No, that didn't work.  I have added a plunker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not watching the value of `attrs.resize`; you are watching the value *pointed by* `attrs.resize` instead, in the test case a scope member called `isHidden`. This does not exist, thus the `undefined`.

For what you aare trying to do, the following would work:

```
App.directive('resize', function($animate) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(
            // NOTE THE DIFFERENCE HERE
            function() {
                return element.attr("resize");
// EDIT: Changed in favor of line above...
//              return attrs.resize;
            },
            function(newVal) {
                if(newVal) {
                    $animate.addClass(element, 'span8');
                }
            }
        );
    };
});
```

---

**EDIT:** It seems that the `attrs` object does *NOT* get updated from DOM updates for non-interpolated values. So you will have to watch `element.attr("resize")`. I fear this is not effective though... See forked plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/iBNpha33e2Xw8CHgWmVx?p=preview

Comment: I'd use `attrs.$observe` in this case.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code in for my directive and it still didnt work.  Did I need to change something in the test?

Comment: @package My objection with `$observe` is that it is supposed to watch *interpolated* values. It seems that the `attrs` object does *NOT* get updated from DOM updates for non-interpolated values. Updating the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was able to make this test work.  I am passing in a variable as an `attr` to the directive.  The variable name is `isHidden`.  Here is my test with the updated code that is working.

```
describe('resize', function() {
  var element, scope;
  beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    var directive = angular.element('<div class="span12" resize="isHidden"></div>');
    element = $compile(directive)($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
    scope = $rootScope;
  }));

  it('should change to a span8 after resize', function() {
    expect($(element).hasClass('span12')).toBeTruthy();
    expect($(element).hasClass('span8')).toBeFalsy();
    element.scope().isHidden = true;
    scope.$apply();
    expect($(element).hasClass('span8')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I am able to access the variable `isHidden` through the scope that is attached to the `element`.  After I change the variable, the I have to run `$digest` to update and then all is golden.

I feel that I should probably be using `$observe` here as was noted by `package`.  I will look at that and add a comment when I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

As Nikos has pointed out the problem is that you're not watching the value of attrs.resize so what you can try doing is this:

Create a variable to hold your data and create these $watch functions:

```
var dataGetter;

scope.$watch(function () {
    return attrs.resize;
}, function (newVal) {
    dataGetter = $parse(newVal);
});

scope.$watch(function () {
    return dataGetter && dataGetter(scope);
}, function (newVal) {
    // Do stuff here         
});
```

What should happen here is that Angular's `$parse` function should evaluate `attrs.resize` and return a function like [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse). Then you pass it the scope and do something. As long as `attrs.resize` is just a boolean then newVal in the 2nd watch expression should be a boolean, I hope.